# Show that the distance $d(x)$ of a point $x = (x_k)\in \ell_\infty$ to $c_0$ is equal to $\limsup_{k\to\infty} |x_k|.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Question: Show that the distance $d(x)$ of a point $x = (x_k)\in \ell_\infty$ to $c_0$ is equal to $\limsup_{k\to\infty} |x_k|.$
>           Thus the norm in $\ell_\infty / c_0$ is $\|\hat{x}\| = \limsup_{k\to\infty} |x_k|.$

My attempt:

Note that 
        $$ \|x+c_0\| = \inf_{y\in c_0}\sup_{k\geq 1} |x_k-y_k| \quad\text{and}\quad \limsup_{k\to\infty} |x_k| = \inf_{n\geq 1} \sup_{k\geq n}|x_k| .
  $$
        Pick any $n\geq 1.$
        Let $y = (y_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be such that $y_k = x_k$ for all $k\leq n$ and $y_k = 0$ for all $k\geq n+1.$
        Clearly $\lim_{k\to\infty} y_k = 0$ and so $y\in c_0.$
        It follows that 
        $$ \sup_{k\geq n}|x_k| = \sup_{k\geq 1}|x_k-y_k| \geq \inf_{y\in c_0} \sup_{k\geq 1} |x_k-y_k|.
  $$
        Since $n\geq 1$ is arbitrary, we conclude that 
        $$ \inf_{y\in c_0}\sup_{k\geq 1} |x_k-y_k|\leq \inf_{n\geq 1} \sup_{k\geq n}|x_k| .
  $$

On the other hand, pick any $y\in c_0.$
        Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
        Then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\geq N,$ we have $|y_k|<\epsilon.$
        It follows that 
        $$ \sup_{k\geq 1} |x_k-y_k| \geq \sup_{k\geq N}|x_k-y_k| \geq \sup_{k\geq N} \left( |x_k| - |y_k| \right) \geq \sup_{k\geq N}\left( |x_k| - \epsilon \right) = \sup_{k\geq N} |x_k| - \epsilon \geq \inf_{n\geq 0} \sup_{k\geq n}|x_k| - \epsilon.
  $$
        Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have 
        $$ \sup_{k\geq 1}|x_k-y_k| \geq \inf_{n\geq 1}\sup_{k\geq n} |x_k|.
  $$
        Since $y\in c_0$ is also arbitrary, we conclude that 
        $$ \inf_{y\in c_0}\sup_{k\geq 1}|x_k-y_k| \geq \inf_{n\geq 1}\sup_{k\geq n} |x_k|.
  $$

---

Is my proof above correct?

Comment: Looks OK.  If $(x_k-y_k)_k$ is any  sequence then  $ \sup_k|x_k-y_k|\ge \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{k>n}|x_k-y_k|.$ And if $y_k\to 0$ then $\lim \sup_k|x_k-y_k|=\lim \sup_k|x_k|.$